# Porque meu carousel bootstrap não está funcionando?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Porque meu carousel bootstrap não está funcionando ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <title>Marcos Briseno - Livros</title>

 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-secondary">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Curso</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">


    <ul class=" navbar-nav mr-auto">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perfil</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços </a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Depoimentos</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contatos</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navDrop">
       Social
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Facebook</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Twitter</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Instagram</a>
      </div>

     </li>

    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline flex-nowrap">
     <input class="form-control ml-lg-4 mr-2 " type="search" placeholder="Buscar...">
     <button class="btn-inline btn-dark" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>


 </nav>
 <div id="carouselSite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">

   <div class="carousel-iten active">
    "
    <div class="carousel-iten">
     <img src="img/image1.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-iten">

     <img src="img/image2.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-iten">

     <img src="img/image3.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block">
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua`<div class="carousel-iten active">` está fechada no lugar errado, vc colocou todos os slides dentro dela, isso é errado, outro detalhe, por boa prática convém colocar todos os arquivos `.JS` no final do documento!

Outra coisa, `item` se escreve com `M` no final, o correto da classe é `carousel-item` e não `carousel-iten` como está no seu código...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Lei a documentação completa do Slider oficial https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Seu código funcionando com os erros corrigidos

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-secondary">
  <div class="container">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Curso</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">


    <ul class=" navbar-nav mr-auto">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Perfil</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Serviços </a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Depoimentos</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contatos</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navDrop">
       Social
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Facebook</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Twitter</a>
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Instagram</a>
      </div>

     </li>

    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline flex-nowrap">
     <input class="form-control ml-lg-4 mr-2 " type="search" placeholder="Buscar...">
     <button class="btn-inline btn-dark" type="submit">OK</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>


  </nav>
  
 <div id="carouselSite" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
     <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/100" class="w-100 d-block">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/100" class="w-100 d-block">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
     <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/100" class="w-100 d-block">
    </div>
   
  </div>
  </div>
  


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```